# Short sample in a 4-point bending test ( ASTM C 393 )

Tags: product-testing

I would load a sample measuring 130 mm long in the 4-point bending test (ASTM C393)

According to the standard, the sample should be 150 mm long.

Top layers consist of laminates (laminates are Fiber-reinforced composite )

Can I do the test on the 130 mm sample?

Comment: solution to what? clarify what you are asking.

Comment: If I can take the length of sample 130 mm.

Answer (score 2):

Standards are established for a reason: so that tests are conducted to an established procedure so that the results are comparable. If the standard calls for a length of 150 mm then that is what is required.

A non-standard test can be conducted on a different length sample, but you then have to make adjustments to the results and the results may not be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

if performing a standard compliant test is important be sure to read and understand the actual standards document. There are typically formula for parameters the give ranges of permissible dimensions.

Did you do that, is 150 the minimum?

If you can not meet the standard, you can of course do the test and report the data with an asterisk, but it is important you should understand why the parameters limits are what they are. The reasoning is explained in the standards document.  In some cases you are exceeding the accuracy bounds of the beam theory used for stress calculation (for example). In other cases you may risk generating a completely different mode of failure.

Sorry to be general about it, but I think Its to you to go study the standard and ask more specific questions if you need help.